# Using a name attribute in a javascritpt .forEach method

Tags: javascript, foreach

So I have 5 buttons at the top of my webpage:

```
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox" name="mailbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent" name="mailbox">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived" name="mailbox">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
```

As you can see, I've already given all 5 buttons the same class because I'm using Bootstrap and I've already given them all individual id's. The problem is I want to apply a function to just three of the buttons (inbox, sent and archive) so I planned on giving 3 of the buttons the same name attribute. I discovered that if you want to use name in document.querySelectorAll() I can give the 3 mailboxes a name attribute of "mailbox" and then do something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="mailbox"]')
```

But at the end of this querySelectorAll I want to add a .forEach() but I can't figure out how I would do that. Would it be something like this? :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="mailbox"]').forEach([name="mailbox"] => {
  [name="mailbox"].onclick = function(){....
}
```

Alternatively I saw that you can use multiple id's in querySelectorAll but then I ran into the same problem of not really knowing how to correctly syntax the rest of the statement:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#inbox, #sent, #archive').forEach(inbox, sent, archive)...?
```

Comment: `.forEach(elem=> {
 elem.onclick = func...` A selector string like `[name=mailbox]` is just for selecting elements from the DOM. Once you've called `querySelectorAll`, and it returns its result, you can call `.forEach()` on the returned collecdtion of elements. The elements are like JS objects, so you just reference and generally  use the like objects. So in the example I gave above, `elem` is the current element in the iteration of the matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use a common `class` for those three buttons.

Then, you can put the result of the `querySelectorAll` in an array and iterate over each element using `forEach` to set the `click` listeners:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const mailboxElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.mailbox')];
  mailboxElements.forEach(mailboxElement => {
    mailboxElement.onclick = function(){
      console.log("mailboxElement: " + this.id);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mailbox" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mailbox" id="sent">Sent</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mailbox" id="archived">Archived</button>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: thank you, I've tried this and I do believe this is the right answer but I am having other errors so I'm unsure. I'm getting `inbox.js:74 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/inbox 500 (Internal Server Error)` and `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: @sarchi-xo these are probably server-side errors or parsing-related. Please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.